# SignalR hub Context.ConnectionId object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I went through a bunch of tutorials for SignalR and sending messages to a specific client. I am getting the following:

Error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HubBase.Context'

Code:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{

    public string msg = "Initializing and Preparing...";
    public int counter = 1;

    public static void SendMessage(string msg, int count)
    {
        var message = msg;
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        //Context.ConnectionId throwing error
        hubContext.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendMessage(string.Format(message), count); 
    }

    public void GetCountAndMessage()
    {
        Clients.Caller.sendMessage(string.Format(msg), counter);
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong the line Context.connectionId is the exact same line they use yet mine is giving an object reference error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you are trying to access the non-static [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.0) property in your static method, which is not possible (see [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) for further information). An option to resolve this issue would be making the `SendMessage` method non-static by removing the `static` keyword.